# Row selection and deselection in kendo grid using checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using kendo grid and check box in the grid.I have an option to check all the rows using checkbox and uncheck them too.Its working perfectly.Now when i check a individual row the row is getting selected.But when i uncheck the row its not clearing the selection.I am using the following code.

```
$("#refegrid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: griddataSource,
            pageable: true,
            selectable: "multiple",
            sortable: true,
            filterable: false,
            reorderable: true,
            scrollable: false,
            columns: [
                {
                    field:"check_item",title:"<input type='checkbox' id='chkSelectAll' onchange='SelectAll();'/>",template:"<input type='checkbox' id='inpchk' onchange='chkOrUnchk()'/>",width:'50px',sortable:false
                }
            ],
            editable: "inline",
        });

function chkOrUnchk(){
        $('tr.k-state-selected','#refegrid').removeClass('k-state-selected');
    }
```

//Function for selecting/deselecting all records

```
function SelectAll(){
        if ($("#chkSelectAll").attr('checked')) { 
            $("#refegrid").each(function () {
                var $row    = $(this);
                var checked = $row.find('#inpchk').attr('checked');
                $row.find("#inpchk").attr('checked', 'checked');
                //$(this).addClass('k-state-selected');
            }); 
        }
        else {                   
            $("#refegrid").each(function () {
                var $row = $(this);
                $row.find("#inpchk").removeAttr('checked');
                //$(this).removeClass('k-state-selected');
            }); 
        }           
    }
```

The commented statements are used for selecting/deselecting all records

I have tried `removeClass()` ethod to clear the selection.But its not working.How to solve the issue.?Any help is much appreciated.?

Comment: Are you sure `chkOrUnchk` is called when you check/uncheck the checkbox? Use `console.log` or `alert` to confirm.

Comment: Yes @Paritosh.The function is called.I have rechecked it

Comment: It seems to me that you are not selecting / deselecting the row but Kendo UI is doing it. Since you have `selectable: "multiple"` if you click anywhere in the row it selects it. Then for deselecting there are two `click` events happening: yours in the checkbox; the default that click in the row. Then what happens is that you disable it and then Kendo UI enables it.

Comment: okay.so how can i deselect the row when the user unchecks the checkbox aganist a row?

Comment: Could you include how you are selecting it so I can post a complete answer?

Comment: @OnaBai Can you look into the updated question.I have updated the code for selecting/deselecting the records